# Pandas: Sort DataFrame Cellls across columns if unordered

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to modify (sort) a Series of data in a Pandas DataFrame?
For example, after importing some data, colums should be in ascending order, but I need to reorder data if it is not.  Data is being imported from a `csv` into a `pandas.df`.

```
           num_1    num_2   num_3
date
2020-02-03  17      22       36
2020-02-06  52      22       14
2020-02-10  5        8       29
2020-02-13  10      14       30
2020-02-17  7        8       19
```

I would ideally find the second row (panda Series) in the Dataframe as the record to be fixed:

```
           num_1    num_2   num_3    num_4     num_5
date
2020-02-06  52      22       14       25         27
```

And modify it to be: ***(Only sorting nums 1-3 and not touching columns 4 & 5)***

```
           num_1    num_2   num_3    num_4   num_5
date
2020-02-06  14      22       52        25      27
```

I could iterate over the DataFrame and check for indexes that have Series data out of order by comparing each column to the column to it's right.  Then write a custom sorter and rewrite that record back into the Dataframe, but that seems clunky.

I have to imagine there's a more Pythonic (Pandas) way to do this type of thing.  I just can't find it in the pandas documentation.  I don't want to reorder the rows just make sure the values are in the appropriate order within the columns.

***Update***: I forgot to mention one of the most critical aspects.  There are other columns in the DataFrame that should not be touched.  So in the example below, only `sort` (`num_1, num_2, num_3`) not the others. I'm guessing I can use the solutions posed already, split the DataFrame, sort the first part and re-merge them together.   Is there an alternative?

Comment: You could use ``DataFrame.sort_values`` by setting ``axis = 1``

Comment: this doesnt work, what about the 'by' parameter?

Comment: Need to use `numpy` in this case. Well should as it avoids the painfully slow `apply(axis=1)` . The most concise solution (cs95's idea) is `df[:] = np.sort(df, axis=1)`

Comment: All - thanks for the feedback.  I will start by trying a few of these out.  I realized now I missed a critical part to this question.  I will update it now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df.apply(sorted, axis=1)),columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```